# Jenkins build fails with Compilation error when I remove "clean" from maven goals for the build

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, log4j

I have a maven project composed of 2 modules and I run it on Jenkins continuous integration. Previously I wrote the maven goals "clean test package" and it runs normally.

Now I want to use incremental build so I don't want to explicitly execute the "clean" phase. When I remove "clean" from maven goals, it runs only the second module of the project and the build fails with the following error in the JUnit Test Class:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project DemoProject: 
Compilation failure: package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
```

Do anyone have an idea about what is happenning here ?

Comment: You should only us `mvn package` instead of `mvn test package` otherwise several things running more than once.

Comment: it worked correctly for a build, but when I updated the code and pushed it on the git repo and rebuilt the job, it only builds the 2nd module and fails with the same error above

Comment: You are missing a dependency cause your build fails with compile error.

Comment: But it works correctly on eclipse, and I ran it many successful times on jenkins. It only started to fail 4-5 days ago when i added the incremental build part.I tried removing it again and it didn't work also

Comment: What kind of incremental build parts? The final check is only from command line only cause in Eclipse there are differences between command line and Eclipse (Eclipse is doing things wrong).

Comment: I used maven-compiler-plugin's <useIncrementalCompilation>

Comment: It now works, thanks for your kind support. I found out there was a problem with the dependency as you said before, It looks like the files were not downloaded correctly. Also when I set maven goals to `mvn package` only it worked with the incremental build without using 'clean' phase ^~^

Comment: If you download issues start using [checksum policy](https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/)...